# Trying to understand how recaptcha works step by step

Tags: recaptcha

This is my current understanding of recaptcha (using v2 invisible)

- We load the api.js script onto our site
- We add data attributes to the button
- User clicks button
- A listener somewhere in the api.js script fires because it's listening for an event on a tag with those data attributes
- This is where it gets fuzzy and I start guessing:
- api.js gathers browsing info from the user's cookies and information about how they interacted with the site. Based on this it determines how likely you are are to be a bot and if you are below a certain threshold it gives you a test. Whether you pass the test then gets further factored into your score and all of that gets encoded into a token, which we receive in our callback that we specified on the button's data attribute.
- We pass this token to the back end with the rest of our form
- From the backend, we make an API request to Google to convert the token into usable information about whether the user passed or failed.

At this point I get confused about why this wasn't just what the api.js script returned in the first place. Does this step only exist in order to give Recaptcha information to further improve it? I just don't understand why this step is here, unless I'm misunderstanding what is going on earlier in the process. Am I getting these we steps wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point for captchas is that your *server* (instead of client in the browser) can verify that the (HTTP) request it received was generated from a real person's actions, when interacting with your application.

This is why your client sends a recaptcha token to your server and your backend consults with the captcha provider about this token and receives trusted information about the original client. In this scenario, your server does not trust the client, so it receives only a token from it. Then it communicates with the trusted captcha provider server-to-server and validates that the token it received from the client is valid and the user behind it is legitimate.

If your client sent the original response from the captcha provider to your backend server, there would be no way for your server to know whether this was a legitimate response from the captcha provider, or a fake one from the client.

Comment: So the endpoint on the server has logic to communicate with Google to perform the validation?

Comment: Yes. So, for recaptcha specifically, your backend server would need to make a request to the [verify endpoint on Google's servers](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)